# R data.table not working: dt[, literal_column = variable1_as_string == variable1_as_string]

Tags: r, data.table

I gueess my question boils down to this: how can I give column name as a parameter (in a variable) instead of literal on the RHS of an R data.table line?

My sample problem:

This works:

```
input_table[, temp_logical := 
              input_table[,ID_lag_0] == 
              input_table[,ID_lag_1]]
```

This (Part1) works:

```
# ... K > 0 at this point
ID_shifted_newcol_names = paste("ID_lag_", 0:K, sep = "")    

input_table[, eval(ID_shifted_newcol_names[1]) := ID] #lag 0 element
for(k in 1:K){ #elements with lag 1...k
    input_table[, eval(ID_shifted_newcol_names[k+1]) := shift(ID, type = "lag", n = k)]
}
```

So far so good, so LHS below should work as intended, RHS must be problematic, this (Part2) does not work:

```
#now test if lagged and previous ID row are different
for(k in 1:K){

input_table[, temp_logical := 
                  eval(input_table[,ID_shifted_newcol_names[k]) == 
                  eval(input_table[,ID_shifted_newcol_names[k+1]) # always F
}
```

The result is always F; I am guessing it is due to comparing eval of two strings instead of values of two different names.

Now I tried encapsulating eval (and without eval) into 'as.name', 'as.symbol', 'deparse(substitute(...))', but could not get it to work.